# How to get a user's IP address in PHP?

Tags: php, ip

I am using below code to get the user's real IP address.

```
function getUserIP () {

    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')) {

        $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');

    }

    elseif (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {

        $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');

    }

    elseif (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')) {

        $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');

    }

    elseif (getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')) {

        $ip = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');

    }

    elseif (getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')) {

        $ip = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');

    }

    else {

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    }

    return $ip;

}

$userIP = getUserIP();
```

Sometimes I am getting that the IP address is `67.143.220.112, 67.142.171.26`.

Is that the correct IP address of the user or do I have to do something else to get the real IP address of the user?

Comment: Your way seems fine. For a more detailed blog discussion : http://www.scriptygoddess.com/archives/2003/03/18/get-users-ip-with-php/

Comment: Use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] Also, may i suggest [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) for clarity?

Answer (score 4):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` gives the user's IP address.

Comment: It only gives the address of the machine which originated the TCP connection to the server, which may NOT be the user's actual address.

Answer (score 2):

Perfect method to get User IP address.

```
<?PHP

function getUserIP()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}


$user_ip = getUserIP();

echo $user_ip; // Output User IP address [Ex: 177.87.193.134]


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only 100% reliable address you can get is `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. The other headers are optional, not always present, and are trivially forged, since they're informational only.

Even the REMOTE_ADDR one will be wrong if the user is behind one or more proxies and/or NAT gateways. In short, there's no foolproof way to perfectly identify a user's real IP address regardless of proxying/NATing.