# Print out a city with the users IP adress

Tags: php, json, api, ip, maps

For a little project of mine i want to print the city (the name) on the screen with the ip of the user, i already have something to get his/her IP but i dont how to get the city where he/she is from....

the code i use right now to get the ip+:

```
function getUserIP()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}


$user_ip = getUserIP();

echo $user_ip; // Output IP address [Ex: 177.87.193.134]
```

credits: [How to get a user's IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919160/how-to-get-a-users-ip-address-in-php)

does anyone have an idea how i should get it to work? 
You dont have to write something for me, 
but a hint or a link to a othore tread would really help!
Tips are always welcome!

Comment: Look into GeoIP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

Comment: Thanks for your tip!